# Получается кривая анимация

Tags: jquery, css

Анимация получается некорректная. Пиксели перестраиваются.
http://aleshkalavrushka.tk/
Здесь показано что я имею ввиду
Как это исправить?

```
$(function () {
     var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
     $('#show_info_panel').click(function(e) {
         $info_panel.toggleClass('slide_panel');
     });
 });
```

### Всё остальное на css.

fori1ton, вы были правы. Проверил на chrome - всё норм. Но по поводу плагинов ещё не понятно. На firefox же плагины работают нормально. А мой код нет. Я в JS не очень. Может можно как-нибудь оптимизировать код, чтобы всё работало нормально на всех браузерах? И, извиняюсь за тавтологию.

Comment: вроде вполне нормально выезжает. только круг в центре не круглый.

Comment: Постарайтесь приводить самодостаточные примеры прямо здесь, а не ссылаться на внешние ресурсы, особенно если пример там проживёт несколько часов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в анимации. Такое явление называется [screen tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing), и вызвано оно ошибками либо плохой оптимизацией программы, отображающей анимацию (в вашем случае - браузера). Исправить это на странице вы не сможете, нужно разбираться с настройками браузера. Причиной этого может быть то, что у вас в браузере не включена поддержка GPU ускорения, либо не установлены (криво установлены) драйвера видеокарты, либо ещё что-либо (только для Firefox поиск по фразе `firefox screen tearing` даёт с десяток возможных причин и способов решения).

Comment: Но я смотрел другие плагины, делающие абсолютно тоже самое. И мой браузер работает с ними нормально. Значит проблема в коде, разве нет?

Comment: Либо плохой оптимизацией браузера. Уже сменил систему. Всё ок!